# Unable to connect to the Jfrog Artifactary from Docker containers

Tags: docker, artifactory

I have built a docker image to build the java code with java, maven, and git. I was able to clone the code to Docker container but when it is trying to build the code docker is was unable to connect to jfrog artifactary to bring the dependencies.

So I tried to ping the artifactary from the container but it was unable to ping.

Can someone help me how can I connect to the artifactary from docker containers.

Comment: Please double check if you using any http proxy, maybe you forgot to configure it for Docker deamon

Comment: How are you trying to connect from the docker container to Artifactory? Are they placed on the same machine? How did you installed Artifactory? how are you trying to pull dependencies? (docker? Maven? git VCS?) a lot of information is missing in order to try and assist you with the issue.

Comment: I have installed the dockers on my local machine and the artifactary is installed on the server. I am trying to build the java code using maven then maven is failing to get the dependencies from artifactary.